# Switch Options and Defult

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I have an assignment I am doing for school. I have pretty much got it 99% completed but I am struggling with this last thing.

The last switch option needs to do a calculation provided the person using it pushes the '1' key. If not, it will give a message saying incorrect key.

My issue is that it does the calculation without any issue but even if the person pushes anything other than the '1' it still completes the calculation.

What am I missing?

```
int option, quantity; 
    float childTotal=0; 
    final double childCost=18.00; 
    float adultTotal=0;
    final double adultCost=36.00;
    float seniorTotal=0;
    final double seniorCost=32.50;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //InputStream initialisation


    System.out.println("@@@@@  Welcome to Zoo Victoria  @@@@@");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Please choose from the following ticket type");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1 = Child (4-5 years)");
    System.out.println("2 = Adult (18+ years)");
    System.out.println("3 = Senior (60+ years)");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter your ticket type");
    option=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the total number of tickets to be purchased");
    quantity=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("You wish to purchase " +(quantity));
    switch (option) {
        case 1: System.out.println (" child tickets at $18.00");
                break;
        case 2: System.out.println (" adult tickets at $36.00");
                break;
        case 3: System.out.println (" senior tickets at $32.50");
                break;
        }
    System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm purchase");
    option=input.nextInt();
    {
        switch (option) {
        case 1: childTotal=(float) (childTotal + (childCost * quantity));
                System.out.println(childTotal);
                break;
        case 2: adultTotal=(float) (adultTotal + (adultCost * quantity));
                System.out.println(adultTotal);
                break;
        case 3: seniorTotal=(float) (seniorTotal + (seniorCost * quantity));
                System.out.println(seniorTotal);
                break;
        default:
                System.out.println("Incorrect Key");
        }

 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before the second `switch`,you can do some check to determine if further process continues or not

Answer (score 0):

I believe its cause you are using the same variable for two different operations.
like here :

You re-initialized the option variable, then used it again  on intending to use  the first  option = input.nextInt()

```
option = input.nextInt();

switch (option) {
    case 1:
        childTotal = (float) (childTotal + (childCost * quantity));
        System.out.println(childTotal);
        break;
    case 2:
        adultTotal = (float) (adultTotal + (adultCost * quantity));
        System.out.println(adultTotal);
        break;
    case 3:
        seniorTotal = (float) (seniorTotal + (seniorCost * quantity));
        System.out.println(seniorTotal);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Incorrect Key");
}
```

**Possible Solution:**

```
System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm purchase");
        if(input.nextInt() == 1){




        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                childTotal = (float) (childTotal + (childCost * quantity));
                System.out.println(childTotal);
                break;
            case 2:
                adultTotal = (float) (adultTotal + (adultCost * quantity));
                System.out.println(adultTotal);
                break;
            case 3:
                seniorTotal = (float) (seniorTotal + (seniorCost * quantity));
                System.out.println(seniorTotal);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Incorrect Key");
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("err");
            // do what you want
        }
```

Comment: Thanks all for the responses.

I actually figured it out this morning by using an if/else statement.